# Unexpected Result When Using Fibers

Tags: ruby

I wrote a simple ruby fiber program to see how they work and got an unexpected result.

```
#! /usr/bin/env ruby
#encoding: utf-8
#frozen_string_literal: true

sg = Fiber.new do
  File.open(begin print "Enter filename: "; gets.chomp end).each{|l| Fiber.yield l}
end

begin
  loop do
    puts sg.resume
  end
rescue => err
  puts "Error: #{err.message}"
end
```

datafile

```
This is the first
This is the second
This is the third
This is the fourth
This is the fifth
```

And the output from the above program

```
Enter filename: datafile
This is the first
This is the second
This is the third
This is the fourth
This is the fifth
#<File:0x0000557ce26ce3c8>
Error: attempt to resume a terminated fiber
```

I'm not sure why its displaying #File:0x0000557ce26ce3c8 in the output.

Note: ruby 3.0.2p107 (2021-07-07 revision 0db68f0233) [x86_64-linux-gnu]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Fiber.html),

> Upon yielding or termination the `Fiber` returns the value of the last executed expression

In addition to `Fiber.yield` calls, a fiber (like an ordinary function) returns the result of the final expression in the fiber.

The body of your fiber is this.

```
File.open(begin print "Enter filename: "; gets.chomp end).each{|l| Fiber.yield l}
```

Inside the `.each`, you yield each line of the file, which gets printed out as you've already observed. But then, when the fiber is done, it yields a final value, which is the result of [`File.open`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/File.html#method-c-open). And `File.open` returns the `File` object itself. So your `sg.resume` actually sees six results, not five.

```
"This is the first"
"This is the second"
"This is the third"
"This is the fourth"
"This is the fifth"
(the file object itself)
```

This actually points out a small issue in your program to begin with: You never close the file. You can do that either with `File#close` or by passing a block to `File::open`. In order to be completely safe, your fiber code should probably look like this.

```rb
sg = Fiber.new do
  print "Enter filename: "
  filename = gets.chomp
  # By passing File.open a block, the file is closed after the block automatically.
  File.open(filename) do |f|
    f.each{|l| Fiber.yield l}
  end
  # Our fiber has to return something at the end, so let's just return nil
  nil
end

begin
  loop do
    # Get the value. If it's nil, then we're done; we can break out of the loop.
    # Otherwise, print it
    value = sg.resume
    break if value.nil?
    puts value
  end
rescue => err
  puts "Error: #{err.message}"
end
```

Now, in addition to dealing with that pesky file handle, we have a way to detect when the fiber is done and we no longer get the "attempt to resume a terminated fiber" error.

Comment: Note: If you pass a block to File.open then it will automatically close the File object when the block finishes.

Comment: Thanks, looks like I forgot to make that explicit. Edited.